# Drupal CiviCRM Rules module: How to use the action "CiviCRM Mailing: Send email"?

Tags: civimail, drupal-rules

I need to schedule CiviMail mailings through Drupal rules. I see that the **CiviCRM Rules Integration** module has an action labeled "CiviCRM Mailing: Send email" but it's not clear what this action is supposed to do. My assumption was that it would create a scheduled CiviMail bulk mailing. But this is the default body text, which confused me:

```
A new mailing has been scheduled: {mailing.name}

{mailing.viewUrl}
You can review the mail here: {mailing.editUrl}
You can schedule the mail for here: {mailing.scheduleUrl}

The content of the email is:
<pre>
{mailing.html}
</pre>
```

I don't understand. Can this rules action be used to schedule a CiviMail mailing? Or is it intended for a different purpose? Any experience or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration of CiviMail with the rules module is primarily for workflow purposes. i.e. they allow another person to approve a scheduled email. Thus a CiviMail has to be scheduled and approved before it can be sent out (if this has been enabled within CiviMail settings screens)

The action by itself does not create or schedule a CiviMail. It just approves it and/or sends it back to the creator (a link via email) for further edits and revisions.

This was work done in support of the New York State Senate's usage of CiviCRM an CiviMail

Comment: Thanks, Lobo! This is exactly the info I needed. I went ahead and wrote my own Rules action that creates and schedules a CiviMail bulk mailing: https://github.com/LunkRat/civimail_tools

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but still relevant I think: The new extension CiviRules is developed this spring. This extension aims at doing the same for CiviCRM that DrupalRules does for Drupal. That could then cover your problem natively in CiviCRM.

Check: https://civicrm.org/blogs/erikhommel/civirules-sprint-january-and-march-2015 and/or http://redmine.civicoop.org/projects/civirules/wiki

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My use-case requires Drupal rules, however, because my mailing content is being built from content in Drupal. I want to do exactly what @mathieu explains here: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35187.0